# Eclipse debugging of Android app taking too long

Tags: android, eclipse, performance

I've got a medium sized Android application (17.6 meg) which takes 1 min 45 seconds to for eclipse to load in debug mode. If I choose "run as" (as opposed to "debug as") it takes 15 seconds to load. Is there anything I can do to speed up the process?

Note, Load time has been inching up as the project has grown but the latest addition of the Amazon Wireless SDK (4.4 meg) pushed it into the territory of untenable.

BTW, the APK doesn't show up in the bin folder until 1 min 13 sec after the "debug as" has started - is this normal? Shouldn't it show up right after the "build"?.

Comment: What is the spec of your PC?

Comment: Does your project depend on set of heavy libraries? It might be the reason

Comment: I'm debuggon on a Device. My PC is fast Quad core 3 Ghz 8GB. The AWS SDK does rely heavily on libraries - but 1.5 minutes per download?

Comment: @scoleman2272 You are lucky. How about 13 minutes on my device? 2.5 GH 4 GB ram. It mostly depended by the app. :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing `Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM)` from Android SDK Manager?

Requirements:

-Intel® processor with support for VT-x, EM64T, and Execute Disable (XD) Bit functionality

You can find more about it [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-microsoft)

Comment: I've always found the debugging on the device is much faster than on an emulator. Is this not true?

Comment: @scoleman2272 Yes it is when the app has been transferred on the device. For me it has always been easier to do the debugging on the emulator.